# 3-phase Motor RPM depends on power line frequency?

Tags: motor, frequency, rpm

I have a 3-phase motor but my knowledge on the topic is almost null.
But, you know, I have also curiosity to satisfy.

The motor's nameplate reads:

```
50 Hz, 7.5kW, 
400V, 13.8A / 690V, 8.0A
cos phi 0.89
2910/min

60 Hz, 8.6kW,
460V, 13.5A
cos phi 0.89
3492/min
```

It looks like the RPM is proportional to power line frequency. Is this true? Applying i.e. 340V 50Hz, may I assume that the RPM remains 2910/min?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a squirrel cage induction motor.  The synchronous speed \$n_S\$ (speed of the magnetic field pulling the rotor) is:

$$n_S = \frac {120 f}{P}$$
where f is frequency and P is the number of poles.

You have a 2 pole machine, which gives a \$n_S\$ of 3000rpm at 50Hz and 3600rpm at 60Hz.

It's an induction machine, because rotor speed n is 97% of \$n_S\$.  Slip is 3% at full-load.

To answer the question.

At 340V, 50Hz, the motor will spin at 2910rpm **dependent** on the load torque.

$$ T \ \alpha \ V^2$$

Torque is proportional to the Voltage squared.  340V is 85% of 400V, so load torque would be approximately 72.3% [\$(85\%)^2\$] of full-load torque at 400V.

If the actual load torque was greater than this, the motor speed would slow down to drive the load.  Slip would increase.

[image: SCIM torque vs speed]

Edit...

[Torque Reference](https://www.electrical4u.com/torque-equation-of-three-phase-induction-motor/)

[image: T vs voltage]

Red line is load torque.  Motor will slow down until it is capable of driving load.

Answer (score 2):

There are different designs of electric motor which can run on a 3-phase supply, and we don't know for sure which you have.  But given that the ratio of RPM to grid frequency is the same in both cases, yes, it is very likely that the speed will stay very similar at 340V.  This assumes that the load is low enough for the motor to run at the reduced voltage, of course.

Comment: its an induction machine. this can be seen due to a speed difference w.r.t. sync speed. 50Hz would equal 3000rpm for a sync machine

Comment: Very probably.  But we can't completely rule out a weird gearbox on a synchronous motor.

Comment: The slip frequency will probably increase (at the same load). If it increases from (3000-2910=) 90 rpm to say 120rpm, the motor would then run at 2880rpm.

Answer (score 0):

S = f * 120 / N

Where:

S = *Synchronous* speed in RPM

f = Frequency in Hz

120 = mathematical constant

N = Number of poles in the motor design

Actual speed = S * (1-Slip %)

So yes, speed of a 3 phase motor is based on the frequency applied to it.